# Cardinality of compacts with positive $(>0)$ Lebesgue measure in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, compactness

I need to prove that it's same as $[0,1]$ (continuum).

Let's say I have proved "fact" that closed balls with positive radius in $\Bbb R^3$ have same cardinality as $[0,1]$.

Does it prove that compacts have cardinality no more than continuum? If so, what I should do in "no less than" part (or vice versa no less than -> no more than)?

Comment: Associate a countable dense subset with each compact set.

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand how this will help with cardinality of compacts. Maximum i know from my course is definition of dense "everywhere".